# Can Oracle SQL*Loader check for extra delimiters?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

From tests done, it seems that loading does not fail if the file contains extra delimiters.

Let say I have a control file with 3 columns a,b,c as follows

```
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"  trailing nullcols
(
a,
b,
c
)
```

But the file contains extra delimiters in some of the rows. As example:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9|10
11|12|13
```

In the above example, row 3 contains an extra delimiter but loading is successful and the last value (10) is not loaded.

Can you specify some option in the control file to treat row 3 as bad or discard?

Validations of the input file can be done prior to loading but wanted to check if the loader itself supports such feature.

Comment: How many columns does your table have?

Comment: It will have 100 to 200 columns. Why columns matter?